# Splunk is Monitoring Its own Logs

Tags: logging, monitoring, splunk

We are trying to monitor log files on a server using the Splunk universal forwarder. The logs directory (say  /logs/app3/Oct2015) is being monitored by Splunk forwarder.

The Splunk documentation tells that the use of blacklist can be done to stop monitoring of any unwanted directory. Accordingly, my input.conf is here with: ([Splunk Documentation](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Data/Monitorfilesanddirectorieswithinputs.conf))

**/opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local/inputs.conf :**

```
[monitor:///logs/app3/Oct2015/]
    sourcetype = access_common
    ignoreOlderThan = 7d
    recurse = true
    _TCP_ROUTING = toLogAggregator
    blacklist = /opt/splunkforwarder/...

[blacklist:/opt/splunkforwarder/...]
```

This is my Output configuration -

**/opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local/outputs.conf :**
([Splunk Documentation on Output](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Forwarding/Configureforwarderswithoutputs.confd))

```
[tcpout]
defaultGroup = toBeIgnored

# This target group will redirect events to Log aggregator listening on TCP socket.
[tcpout:toLogAggregator]
server = 10.20.176.207:9997
sendCookedData = false

[tcpout:toBeIgnored]
```

When I run the Splunk Universal Forwarder (v6.3), I am successfully able to monitor my logs directory, but Splunk is also sending me its own logs. I added a blacklist stanza to stop Splunk from monitoring and sending me its own logs, but no luck. My aggregator server is continuously receiving Splunk logs mixed with logs I am monitoring.

I added a TCP output group to drain events by default and explicitly marked my monitored directory to route logs using a different TCP group, but that also didn't work. Still getting bombarded with Splunk logs.

Does anyone knows, how to tel Splunk Forwarder to not to monitor itself but only monitor the directory I have requested for ?

regards,

-Vipul;

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to receive Splunk's own logs?

Comment: Thanks Oerd for the response.  Let me add more context here:

On the other side of the network connection is a Java application reading from ServerSocket. We are collecting logs from different servers and posting them to HDFS for further hadoop based analysis. The data we are collecting from application servers, is RAW (uncooked) data.

At this point, We are only interested in the application logs that is being watched. Splunk logs are getting mixed with the application log we are trying to analyze. Splunk logs are comparable in size and producing considerable unwanted traffic.

Comment: but splunk logs are in `index=_internal` your data is usually in another index... what is your query? (PS: splunk will pull its logs, you want those, as there is no other way to understand what is wrong with the app logs when something is wrong)

Comment: My requirement is that Splunk on send me my application's logs on the Socket my application is reading from. If there is no way to stop Splunk from reading its own logs, then Alteast it should not forward its logs on my Socket.  Can we tell splunk to Only forward the Application logs on the forwarder we can configured,  i.e.  Server = 10.20.176.207 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a plugin present in /opt/splunkforwarder/etc/apps/ by default, called **SplunkUniversalForwarder**. Inside the plugin directory, there is a default directory that contains an inputs.conf file. This file contains the monitor statements for $SPLUNK_HOME/var/log folder.

I disabled them and Bingo, Splunk stopped flooding the destination with Splunk logs, while sending what I asked Splunk to forward.

All the details are here:
https://answers.splunk.com/answers/320050/how-to-tell-a-splunk-universal-forwarder-to-not-to.html

Comment: Just be wary of editing files in the default folder, changes here will be lost when you upgrade the Splunk Forwarder. You should make a copy of /opt/splunkforwarder/etc/apps/SplunkUniversalForwarder/default/inputs.conf in /opt/splunkforwarder/etc/apps/SplunkUniversalForwarder/local/inputs.conf and then disable it in there. Changes in the local folder will persist upgrades and override anything in default.